# Safety of travelling to Muslim countries/Israel during Ramadan

Tags: safety

Israel and some Muslim countries are amazing travel destinations. But I worry about the safety of the trip.

Are Muslim countries and Israel safe/considerably safer to travel to when it's Ramadan? I'm specially interested in Egypt and Israel.

Comment: Safer compared to what? Just because a country follows a particular religion doesn't make it less safe than others. I've felt less safe in my hometown of Baltimore (US) than I have visiting Indonesia (Muslim country).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: Safer regarding terror attacks.

Comment: And which Muslim countries? Iran is wildly different than Afghanistan in terms of safety.
Also, what do you expect to change in Israel during Ramadan?

Comment: So you're asking whether the incredibly small probability of being caught in a terror attack while you are visiting Israel or Egypt is higher or lower during Ramadan; is that correct?  Whether it's higher or lower, it's still incredibly small.

Comment: Are you interested in travelling to Israel and Egypt in the same trip? When I visited Israel (not recently) I learnt they would not let me in if I had stamps from certain countries in my passport, so I had to apply for a temporary entry permit.

Answer (score 5):

A quick Google search for "terrorist activity during ramadan" shows that nowadays [Ramadan isn't making Muslim places safer](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2017/05/ramadan-isis-attack-muslim/528336/).

On the other hand, I would advise against going to Muslim countries during Ramadan, unless you're Muslim yourself. Activity level is generally lower, many places are closed - including not just bars and nightclubs, but even some swimming pools - and [there are other restrictions](https://www.thenational.ae/uae/ramadan-faqs-everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-holy-month-in-the-uae-1.65949), which depend on the country. Thus you might have issues trying to follow your regular schedule - such as eating or drinking water during the day.